# std::search to find a rightmost subsequence

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, c++14

I am trying to find a rightmost subsequence in a range with `std::search` and `std::make_reverse_iterator`.

However the iterator returned always point to the start of a range. What am I doing wrong?

```
TEST(basic_test, find_from_right)
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> array{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    std::array<uint8_t, 2> subSeq{3, 4};

    auto found = std::search(std::make_reverse_iterator(array.cend()),
                             std::make_reverse_iterator(array.cbegin()),
                             subSeq.cbegin(),
                             subSeq.cend());
// makes no difference
//                             std::make_reverse_iterator(subSeq.cend()),
//                             std::make_reverse_iterator(subSeq.cbegin()));


    auto distance = std::distance(found.base(), array.cbegin());

    EXPECT_EQ(distance, 3);
}
```

Output:

```
Failure
Expected equality of these values:
  distance
    Which is: 0
  3
```

I have a function that is provided with 2 template RandomIterators, so I have to call `std::make_reverse_iterator`. These containers are just for the sake of reproducing the problem and compiling the example.

Comment: You are searching backwards, so the sequence 3, 4 isn't present in your vector. If you searched for 4, 3 it should work.

Comment: @john then what about the uncommented code when I search a subsequence with reversed iterators? It still does not find anything.

Comment: Tried any debugging yet? What where your findings?

Comment: If you're using reverse iterators, but want the offset to the beginning of the searched-for subsequence, then you need to account for the subsequence length. [Example here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07f1ee30864edae1). Fair warning: make damn sure your subsequence was actually found before doing that final calculation.

Comment: @john Well, if I search a subsequence of `{4, 3}` it does find a `reverse_iterator` pointing to the 4th element. I think it may be considered as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this could solve your problem (if you are okay with C++17):

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_end:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
 
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::vector<int>::iterator result;
 
    std::vector<int> t1{1, 2, 3};
 
    result = std::find_end(v.begin(), v.end(), t1.begin(), t1.end());
    if (result == v.end()) {
        std::cout << "sequence not found\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "last occurrence is at: "
                  << std::distance(v.begin(), result) << "\n";
    }
 
    std::vector<int> t2{4, 5, 6};
    result = std::find_end(v.begin(), v.end(), t2.begin(), t2.end());
    if (result == v.end()) {
        std::cout << "sequence not found\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "last occurrence is at: " 
                  << std::distance(v.begin(), result) << "\n";
    }
}
```

So in your case:

```
    auto result = std::find_end(array.begin(), array.end(), subSeq.begin(), subSeq.end());
    if (result == array.end()) {
        std::cout << "sequence not found\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "last occurrence is at: "
                  << std::distance(array.begin(), result) << "\n";
    }
```